# Include public headers of static library in a dynamic framework

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, ios-frameworks

I'm developing a dynamic framework for iOS. This framework uses a static library, which is integrated with `CocoaPods`:

```
+--MyDynamicFramework
   +--PublicHeader1.h
   +--PublicHeader2.h
   +--Sources
   +--Pods
      +--StaticLib
         +--PublicHeader3.h
         +--StaticLib.a
```

Now, I'm using `PublicHeader3.h` (which is part of `StaticLib`) in the sources of my dynamic framework, but I'd also like to expose it as a public header of the dynamic framework I'm building. So an App that uses my dynamic framework should be able to see all three public headers. Is this possible, and if yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Build Settings -> Header Search Path -> Add PATH of MyDynamicFramework/Pods/StaticLib

Comment: How can this make "PublicHeader3.h" public to someone who consumes the "MyDynamicFramework"?